# How to sync Android project by gradle task?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I want to **publish app in one click** in Android Studio.

And I have 3 tasks: increment-version, build-app, and publish-app:

```
increaseVersionCode assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

The task `increaseVersionCode` (my own) just increment versionCode in `build.gradle`, but after that the task `assembleRelease` runs with previous value of versionCode (not incremented). Finally (after all 3 tasks), I have increased versionCode in `build.gradle`, and published app, but with old versionCode.

I think, I should run "Sync Project" after `increaseVersionCode`. But I don't know how to do it with gradle.

Is it possible, to run "Sync Project" of Android Studio by gradle task?

Source of `increaseVersionCode`:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
task('increaseVersionCode') << {
    def buildFile = file("build.gradle")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode\\s+(\\d+)")
    def manifestText = buildFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode " + ++versionCode)
    buildFile.write(manifestContent)
}
```

**UPD, ANSWER**

We need to split command into two bash commands:

```
./gradlew increaseVersionCode && ./gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

Using Android-Studio plugin `BashSupport` we may to run bash scripts from studio. So, we need to put this command into file, and run it with Android-Studio. Thanks to @k3b.

Comment: How do you increase the version code and how do you try to use it in your build task?

Comment: @lu.koerfer it is just simple replace by regex. I attached source code of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note: gradle-scripts are compiled and not interpreted.

gradle compiles all build files and then executes the build. it does not notice that one of it-s own build files has changed after the build-compile so the app is build with the old version info.

i donot know if it is possible to tell gradle to rebuild the build script or execute a sub gradle with a freshly compiled build script

maybe you can create a batch file that you can execute from android studio and that does not depend on android-stuidio-build so you donot have the "tell android studio" issue:

- gradlew increaseVersionCode
- rem a second call to gradlew should recompile the build script
- gradlew clean assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease

Comment: Yes, you are right. Splitting command into two command works fine: `./gradlew increaseVersionCode && ./gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease`. We need only to bind this command to hotkey, or something else. Thank you.